# Displaying Captured Screenshot [Android]

Tags: android, android-screen

I have an app which takes screen shot of a view and saves it in external storage directory. Is it possible to preview the captured image?

I don't want to add any fragments or layouts in my code. Instead, since I know the file name and directory, Is it possible to open the image in **android image viewer** through my app ?

Here's my capture code.

```
public void sharePic(View v)
{
    View captureView = findViewById(R.id.capture);
    captureView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = captureView.getDrawingCache();
    File directory = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/BucketList");
    directory.mkdirs();

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss");
    Date now = new Date();
    String fileIns = formatter.format(now) + ".png";
    File file = new File(directory, fileIns);
    try 
    {
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
        ostream.close();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Screen Captured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Screen Capture Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course that is possible. Does not matter if your app created that file or another app or if it was already there. Your app can request external activities to open any file. As soon as you know the full path of the file you have to configure an Intent and start it. Many examples on this site.

Comment: I didn't really know what to search for. Apparently there are these things called intents. I found it.

    private void showImage() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Intent intent = new Intent();  
  intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);    
  intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "image/png");  
  startActivity(intent);   
 }

Comment: Well does it work? Are you satisfied with it?

Comment: @greenapps : Yup, Works like a charm.